# Сериализация XML Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml, сериализация

Как получить данные из XML, получаемого с сервера яндекс диска?

```
string text = www.downloadHandler.text;
```

Текст имеет вот такой вид: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:"><d:response><d:href>/folder/image.jpg</d:href><d:propstat><d:prop><public_url xmlns="urn:yandex:disk:meta">https://yadi.sk/i/bYlIeaB5x</public_url></d:prop><d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status></d:propstat></d:response></d:multistatus>`
Нужно получить отсюда ссылку, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Вот такая модель данных

```cs
public class PublicUrl
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Prop
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "public_url", Namespace = "urn:yandex:disk:meta")]
    public PublicUrl PublicUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Propstat
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop")]
    public Prop Prop { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "href")]
    public string Href { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "propstat")]
    public Propstat Propstat { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "multistatus", Namespace = "DAV:")]
public class Multistatus
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}
```

И вот так десереализовать

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><d:multistatus xmlns:d=\"DAV:\"><d:response><d:href>/folder/image.jpg</d:href><d:propstat><d:prop><public_url xmlns=\"urn:yandex:disk:meta\">https://yadi.sk/i/bYlIeaB5x</public_url></d:prop><d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status></d:propstat></d:response></d:multistatus>";
    using StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Multistatus));
    Multistatus data = (Multistatus)serializer.Deserialize(reader); // сюда любой Stream или TextReader подойдет

    Console.WriteLine(data.Response.Href);
    Console.WriteLine(data.Response.Propstat.Prop.PublicUrl.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(data.Response.Propstat.Status);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
/folder/image.jpg
https://yadi.sk/i/bYlIeaB5x
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```