# Как создать новую строку с элементом xml unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

мне нужно создавать новый элемент на новой строке в файле xml, но вместо этого, при вызове функции у меня переписывается весь файл

мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

public class playerpref : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string path;
    private void Awake()
    {
        path = Application.dataPath + @"/Resources/UserData.xml";
    }

    public XElement GetElement()
    {
        XAttribute one = new XAttribute("one", "123");
        XAttribute two = new XAttribute("two", "123");

        XElement element = new XElement("userDate", "user", one, two);

        return element;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        XElement root = new XElement("root");
        root.Add(GetElement());
        Debug.Log(root);

        XDocument saveDoc = new XDocument(root);
        File.WriteAllText(path, saveDoc.ToString());
        Debug.Log(path);
    }
}
```

Сейчас при двойном вызове функции строение xml файла такое:

```
<root>
  <userDate one="123" two="123">user</userDate>
</root>
```

Мне нужно, что бы строение выглядело так:

```
<root>
  <userDate one="123" two="123">user</userDate>
  <userDate one="123" two="123">user</userDate>
</root>
```

как это реализовать?

Comment: Все верно, `File.WriteAllText` перезаписывает весь файл. Почему XML? JSON гораздо проще и его декодирование потребляет меньше ресурсов.

Comment: _как это исправить?_ - наверне десерализовать данные файла а объектную модель, добавить туда то что надо и сериализовать обратно.

Comment: Да формирования ответа не хватает описания исходной задачи, а по коду она не ясна. Что там файле должно быть, зачем туда что-либо добавлять? Как вы его планируете читать. Чем вам не угодили встроенные `PlayerPrefs` в движок? Какая именно проблема решается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать такую структуру данных.

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

```cs
public class userRecord
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string one;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string two;

    public userRecord() { }

    public userRecord(string one, string two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
}
```

Написать вот такой метод сохранения

```cs
private void Save(string path, List<userRecord> records)
{
    using (Stream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<userRecord>), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        xs.Serialize(fs, records, ns);
    }
}
```

Создать тестовые данные

```cs
List<userRecord> records = new List<userRecord>();
records.Add(new userRecord("123", "456"));
```

Вот так сохранить

```cs
Save("UserData.xml", records);
```

На выходе получится файл

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <userRecord one="123" two="456" />
</root>
```

Теперь нужен метод загрузки данных из файла

```cs
private List<userRecord> Load(string path)
{
    using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<userRecord>), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
        return (List<userRecord>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

Готово, можно загрузить, добавить строку и сохранить обратно

```cs
List<userRecord> records = Load("UserData.xml");
records.Add(new userRecord("789", "012"));
Save("UserData.xml", records);
```

Получится вот такой XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <userRecord one="123" two="456" />
  <userRecord one="789" two="012" />
</root>
```

---

Примеры сериализации посложнее

- [Записать из документа XML в двумерный массив C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1378808/373567)
- [Генерация файла Xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1142336/373567)
- [Сериализация XML Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1422658/373567)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) У меня есть ещё один вопрос, как "искать" информацию в xml файле? Например проверить, есть ли элемент, у которого один атрибут равен одному значению а другой другому и получить на вывод в Debug.Log его третий атрибут

Comment: @cat00mem десериализуйте его и ищите в объекте модели данных, например с помощью обычного Linq. Как здесь вы получаете список, ищите в нём что хотите, так же и с любой другой моделью данных.

Comment: можно поподробнее пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: @задайте отдельный вопрос, я не понимаю, о чем речь. Кучу примеров уже дал.