# Как десериализовать и сериализировать json unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

мне нужно добавить к JSON элемент, но вместо этого мой скрипт переписывает весь файл. Как это можно реализовать?

JSON файл при двойном вызове функции сейчас:

```
{"id":1,"LoginData":["one","two"],"title":"Student"}
```

Как мне нужно:

```
{"id":1,"LoginData":["one","two"],"title":"Student"},{"id":1,"LoginData":["one","two"],"title":"Student"}
```

Мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class JSONController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UserData userData;
    [System.Serializable]
    public class UserData
    {
        public int id;
        public string[] LoginData;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserBD.json", JsonUtility.ToJson(userData));
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        userData = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserData>(File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserBD.json"));
    }
}
```

Comment: это не XML, это JSON

Comment: Это не ваш случаем вопрос был? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1511918/373567

Comment: Нет, это не мой вопрос, я на него делал опору. XML и JSON перепутал из за видео которое посмотрел

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект в JSON это что-то в фигурных скобах

```
{...}
```

Коллекция в JSON это что-то в квадратных скобках, например коллекция объектов это

```
[{...},{...}]
```

Вы же сейчас просите

```
{...},{...}
```

Это не является валидным JSON, а следовательно вообще не является JSON.

Но допустим, вы такое попросили просто по незнанию или опечатались, допустим вам нужна коллекция объектов.

То есть структура данных у вас будет не `UserData`, а `UserData[]` или `List<UserData>`, массив или список, что для JSON сериализаторов не имеет значения.

Но здесь возникает другая проблема, `JsonUtility` не умеет сериализовать коллекции на верхнем уровне. Варианта решения 2.

#### 1. Инкапсулировать коллекцию в объект

```
public class UserData
{
    public int id;
    public string[] LoginData;
}

public class JsonData
{
    public List<UserData> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда можно вот так создать

```
JsonData data = new JsonData();
data.Items = new List<UserData>();

UserData userData = new UserData();
userData.id = 1;
userData.loginData = new string[] {"one", "two"};
data.Items.Add(userData);
```

Вот так сериализовать

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UserBD.json"), json);
```

Вот так десереализовать

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UserBD.json"));
JsonData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonData>(json);
List<UserData> items = data.Items;
```

#### 2. Использовать другой сериализатор, например JSON.NET

Установить NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json и подключить пространство имен

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Тогда вот так создать

```
List<UserData> items = new List<UserData>();
UserData userData = new UserData();
userData.id = 1;
userData.loginData = new string[] {"one", "two"};
items.Add(userData);
```

Вот так сериализовать

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UserBD.json"), json);
```

Вот так десереализовать

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UserBD.json"));
List<UserData> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(json);
```

Кстати, ставить аттрибут `[Serializable]` для этого сериализатора не требуется.

---

Не используйте `File.AppendAllText`, JSON невозможно дописать в конец файла, так как там есть закрывающие скобки. Нужно перезаписывать файл полностью.

---

Ещё старайтесь избегать вложенных публичных классов. Это может только больше запутать.

Не делайте так

```
class
{
    class { }
}
```

Делайте так

```
class { }

class { }
```

Comment: Использовал первый способ, жалуется на класс с ошибкой The type or namespace name 'UserData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @xyynxs а вы что, класс UserData удалили? Не надо было. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: теперь жалуется на data в сериализации

Comment: @xyynxs у меня плоховато с телепатией

Comment: ошибка The name 'data' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @xyynxs этл значит, что переменная `data` не существует. Вы бы хоть самые базовые основы C# подучили прежде чем за Unity хвататься. Мне тяжело вам советы давать, потому что я не вижу код, и не до конца понимаю цель того, что вы делаете.

Comment: @xyynxs вот https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ позанимайтесь пару вечеров, вам самому эти вопросы покажутся простыми. Не получится писать игры не зная языка.